# Show/Hide Div for Login Mask

Tags: css, javascript, login

I've been trying around a lot to get this working, however every method I tried just didn't want to do as I wanted it to. So here I am.

I have a login-Mask that's only visible if the user is not logged in but it's permanently visible and covers some important areas. So here's my idea: hide it via toggle.

I know it's gonna take HTML, CSS and Javascript, so let's do this.

Here's a visual representation of where I'm at:
[image: the framework]

Now I want the **Login-Widget to only show AFTER you click the "Login" text** up top.

1. Div is hidden by default - CSS: display:none;
2. Text is `<a>`-Element with `href="#"`

So if you click the Text "Login", the Login-Mask appears and if you click it again, it disappears. Just normal toggle.

I guess the best idea is to use `div.toggleClass("open")` or something similar.

**Any help is appreciated!**

**edit01:**
Here's my idea: functions.php

```
<script>
$( "a.toggle").click(function() {
    $("div.log_forms").toggleClass( "open" );
});
</script>
```

**edit02:**

1. jQuery is implemented as seen here
   [image: jQuery, check]
2. The site is loading JavaScript as seen in the other lines in the head-section
3. The code is correct as I've had it work on another site before (tried both # and .)
4. Heck, the script even gets loaded, as seen here
   [image: script here]

Comment: I know links are not a correct way to comment, but taking a look [here](http://codepen.io/dudleystorey/pen/tjzcm) maybe helping you to get another idea?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are calling jQuery wrong by the shorthand `$`.  If you will look in your console you will see an error that `$` is not a function / undeclared etc (this is due to jQuery's conflict mode if I am not wrong).

Your code should look something like this:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
    $( "a.toggle").click(function() {
        $("#log_forms").toggleClass( "open" );
    });
});
</script>
```

Comment: Thank God! It's working! Or rather.. Thank YOU!
It was weird as I knew the code was working  by trying it out a couple different ways, but apparently JS-Code with HTML and jQuery with WordPress is not equal. Once again, thanks a lot!

Comment: @theHubi I'm glad to hear that. Generally, take a look at the browser's `Console` when something like `JavaScript` related doesn't seem to work as expected.

Comment: Well there is a plugin which constantly gives a warning via console, but as it works, I ignore it. I thought the warning was to be attributed to said plugin as well, not my code.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are pretty much there. In your JavaScript you are referencing log_forms as a class, but in your HTML it looks like log_forms is an ID. So you would need:

```
$( "a.toggle").click(function() {
    $("#log_forms").toggleClass( "open" );
});
```

Then the css would be:

```
#log_forms{
    display: none;
}

#log_forms.open{
    display: block;
}
```

Example: [http://jsfiddle.net/diywordpress/nsdbvc4h/9/](https://jsfiddle.net/diywordpress/nsdbvc4h/9/)

Comment: I've tried with both. I added "log_forms" as a class to the div as well.